# Inject packages into Ubuntu live

Tags: 16.04, live-usb, iso

Is it possible to permanently inject/install packages into existing non-persistent Ubuntu live iso?

Comment: *Yes.* There are special tools to create a custom iso file, *but it is difficult.* It is much easier to install packages into a persistent live system or an installed system (installed like into an internal drive, but maybe to a USB drive or memory card).

Answer (score 0):

Try [**LinuxRespin/Remastersys**](https://github.com/ch1x0r/LinuxRespin). 
It can be used to create live bootable ISO from your current installation of Ubuntu/Debian.